# How to restart a django project without refresh session data stored in process/thread space?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

In my django project, I store an instance of a complex class in the thread space. This instance is hard to be serialized so it cannot be stored in the database and resumed from database.

When a request coming, the instance is used to response.

When I refresh the code, I wanna to reload the project without refresh the instance. As the instance keep a lot of information which takes a very long time to construct again.

Is there any way to keep the instance(object that cannot be serialized) when reload django project?

Or is there any way to keep the instance and resume it which cannot be stored in database?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the django cache framework.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/

One can choose from redis, filebased, database, or local ram during development.

example in settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    }
}
```

If you dont want to cache while working on the complex instance, use a non-cache "dummy" cache.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

using this in views

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set('my_key', complex_instance, 30)

complex_instance = cache.get('my_key')
```

Comment: Thank you for your timely reply. I will check if this method could resolve my problem.

Comment: What a pity. I wanna to save the complex instance with `cache.set` and get it with `cache.get`. I found infomation in django document that `value can be any picklable Python object.`. As I mentioned above, the complex instance is impossible to serialized and deserialized. I think this method does not work under this situation.

Comment: After two days, I am still wondering what kind of object cannot be serialized? Maybe another format, like json would help? Is it extremely large? Please let me know if you ever solved this.